# IDA PRO address issue

Tags: reverse-engineering

i'm doing some capture the flag challenges, i struggle when I debug on linux with 'ida'.
Ida shows that ESP points to '0xFFFFC050' but i can't access it.
 here's a picture:
[image]

Comment: You should post this in the Reverse Engineer stack.